# The method replace(String, ArrayList<>) is undefined for the type HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, java-7

I have a code that works okay on my machine:

```
ArrayList<Posting> postings = invertedLists.get(key);
//---- Apply some changes on postings -----     
invertedLists.replace(key, postings);
```

When my friend clones the code it gives her this error:

```
The method replace(String, ArrayList<Posting>) is undefined for the type HashMap<String,ArrayList<Posting>>
```

Note: invertedLists is a `HashMap<String,ArrayList<Posting>>`

We checked in my project; I am using JavaSE-1.6 and she uses JavaSE-1.7.

What can cause this problem?

Comment: Please give a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem. (The code compiles for me.)

Comment: I *suspect* you're actually using Java 8, given that the `replace` method was introduced then...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`Map.replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#replace-K-V-) was first declared in Java 1.8 (see the "since: 1.8" at the bottom). You must be compiling against the 1.8 JDK (even if you're compiling in 1.6 mode). It's possible to do this in an IDE, for instance: to set the language compatibility mode to one version, but compile against the JDK of another version. I've done this on accident a couple times.

Your friend is compiling on "normal" 1.7, which doesn't have that method declared.

Comment: in eclipse: Project -> properties -> java compiler, I see 1.6, where should I check if I am using java 8?

Comment: Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler : 1.4

Comment: found it, maybe it is this: Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs -> there is a java 8 there, checked.

Answer (score 0):

There is no method `replace(K,V)` for  a `HashMap<K,V>`, in [Java 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) , you have to use [JDK 8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) for this.

Answer (score -3):

The method you are looking for is `invertedLists.put(key, postings);`.
EDIT: According to the Java documentation, replace() is not part of the API for HashMap.

Comment: This doesn't explain why it's not compiling on the other machine.

Comment: I believe the question was "_What can cause this problem?_"

Comment: According to the documentation (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), replace is not a method of HashMap in the standard.

Comment: Still not totally correct. `replace()` is indeed part of the `HashMap` API in Java 8.